# Jquery tabs, prevent moving to another tab if active tab has input fields and if they are empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am currently developing a form using jQuery UI tabs for different parts of the form, I managed to prevent moving to another tab if current tab has empty input fields but if on my last tab I have no input field it does not allow me to select another tab, here is an example of the code I am using:

```
    $(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            var content = ui.oldPanel;
            var input = $(content).find('input.i');
            if (input.val()) {
                return true
            }else{
                alert('not allowed')
                return false
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and this is the sample html.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="i" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>
             <input type="text" class="i" />
        </p>
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the third tab has no input field and if I want to return to the second or first tab it does not allow me.
I got the idea of this code from [another stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959344/jquery-ui-tabs-dont-let-user-switch-tabs-if-form-input-in-active-tab-has-conte)

How can I apply the condition only if input tags exist on the tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this issue by checking whether any inputs exist using the `length` property like `if (!$input.length)` as shown below:

```js
$("#tabs").tabs({
  beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
    var $content = ui.oldPanel;
    var $input = $content.find('input.i');
    if (!$input.length)
      return true;
    if ($input.val()) {
      return true
    } else {
      console.log('not allowed')
      return false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>
      <input type="text" class="i" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>
      <input type="text" class="i" />
    </p>
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean
      aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
      nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna
      ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum.
      Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```